# Strange outlines on Edge (old theme)

Tags: bug

There is a strange issue on travel (not seen on stackoverflow) that affects the old (non-beta) theme on Edge.

Anytime you move your mouse over a target (like up/down arrows) an outline is drawn that doesn't go away unless you refresh the page.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I'd argue that this issue will be moot since new themes will be turned on permanently at a certain time though... anyway, no-repro on Edge 42, Windows 10, 100% zoom level, 100% font-size (non-HDPI).

Comment: Which browser and OS are you working with?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional, Edge 42.17134.10 / EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: Having the same thing, change the zoom from 105% to 100% and it's gone.. changed it to any other zoom setting and it worked, only in 105% the lines appear.